# Google Maps + Jquery Autocomplete + Country Filter

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If I am using google maps with jquery ui autocomplete, is it possible to filter by country?

So, if I wanted to display results only in the USA, can I still use the following code:

```
componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
```

It doesnt seem to work as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rr5PL/56/

Any input from someone who has done this before would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate by the same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993049/google-map-geocode-filter-by-country-but-keep-jqueryui-autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have use it like this and it worked for me.

```
 var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'uk'}};
    var input = document.getElementById('points');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
```

points is the id of the textfield which should work with autocomplete

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried to put this code in on my code but the map no longer loads. Maybe I did something wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/Rr5PL/61/

Comment: check this one... http://jsfiddle.net/Rr5PL/63/ I have just added the code to populate the results, you need to alter that to get the map coordinates.

Comment: That is great, but it doesnt use jqueryui autosuggest :(

Comment: I haven't done with the jquery autosuggest. I have used the above mechanism on one of my project. i thought it would help someway. sorry to hear it didn't.